# how can I use singleton or a static instance for my global website settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton, global-variables, static-variables

I have a base web page and used to inherit all of my aspx pages. I have several general method that I have put in base page so that it is available in all inherited aspx pages.

I have one property to get my website settings in this base web page. It is just one record for entire application. I am storing it in Cache.

BaseWebPage.cs property

```
//website settings
public USP_GETWEBSITESETTINGSDETAILS WEBSITESETTING
{
    get
    {
        USP_GETWEBSITESETTINGSDETAILS aWebsiteDetails = null;
        if (Cache["websettings"] != null)
        {
            aWebsiteDetails = (USP_GETWEBSITESETTINGSDETAILS )Cache["WEBSITESETTINGSDETAILS"];
        }
        else
        {
            aWebsiteDetails = GetWebsitesettingsDetails();
            Cache["websettings"] = aWebsiteDetails;
        }
        return aWebsiteDetails;
    }
    set
    {
        Cache["websettings"] = (USP_GETWEBSITESETTINGSDETAILS )value;
    }
}
```

what I want to do is something like

`BaseWebPage.StaticInstance.WEBSITESETTING`, so that I can access common settings on any other page.

Remember I have other properties in this BaseWebPage.cs file like

`CURRENT_USERID`, `CURRENT_USERNAME`, `CURRENT_USER_FULLNAME`, etc. They are similar to above property except the values are stored in Session. For example:

```
public int CURRENT_USERID
{
    get
    {
        int iID = 0;
        if (Session["MYUSERID"] == null)
            iID = 0;
        else
            Int32.TryParse(Session["MYUSERID"].ToString(), out iID);
        return iID;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["MYUSERID"] = (int)value;
    }
}
```

I have read about Singleton and static class and have decent knowledge but not 100% sure about getting it used in proper way to have very good architecture.

If I add below line in BaseWebPage.cs

```
// Singleton instance of this class
public static readonly BasePage StaticInstance = new BasePage();
```

And when I access `BaseWebPage.StaticInstance.CURRENT_USERID` for get/set, is it going to be a single copy for entire application or it will be unique as I am storing it in Session?

Thanks a lot for all suggestions. Please help improve my architecture if you have other good alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well scope of static class in asp.net is global and similar to application object.
So irrespective of your session you will always access the same instance in all session of your asp.net website.

For creating singleton instance don’t use merely static readonly; instead you can have something like below; which is thread safe.

```
//sample code
public sealed class BaseWebPage : Page
{
static BaseWebPage instance=null;
static readonly object padlock = new object();

BaseWebPage()
{
}

public static BaseWebPage Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance==null)
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance==null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

//.. other code
}

Then in any page you can access

BaseWebPage.Instance.WEBSITESETTING  and it will be only single copy for whole application.

I have used this type of code and it worked very well for me.

Comment: Well I have already found several ways to create a singleton class, I am rather interested in a good suggestion about whether I need to use it or static approach or any other alternative. I have several public method in BaseWebPage.cs and as mentioned it is parent of all of my aspx pages so I can't make it 'sealed abstract'

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your BasePage class needs to be a singleton at all. Just make it a regular (perhaps abstract) class and have those properties exist as you have them and just use inheritance.

Comment: I know that, but what you are suggesting is not helpful. I have a BaseMasterPage.cs and several other child master pages. Base master is NOT inherited from BaseWebPage.cs, So if I need to access a public property of BaseWebPage from BaseMasterPage.cs I will have to instantiate it but then it's going to be a per user object (for each new session) which I don't want to.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. Those properties can be static but the class does not have to be.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Singleton pattern many times before but never for the Web. Why don't you just use the Session the way you are doing it with some of your properties? Session is pretty much One instance, to the entire application. In any event, [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998558) you can see the Best Practice from Microsoft. Again, I would not recommend Singleton for a Website at all.

Good luck!